# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, left-join

I have two tables in database and I want to retrieve them by using `left-join`

```
 public Cursor readData()
    {
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, i.Date, i.TimeIn_Info, i.TimeOut_Info, S.Image FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO +"i LEFT JOIN"+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT+" S ON S.Ts_id=i.ID WHERE i.Name = ?", new String[]{"XCV"}, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

However, app crashed. What's wrong here ? Thanks

**LogCat error**

```
 Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 4861
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, i.Date, i.TimeIn_Info, i.TimeOut_Info, S.Image FROM Informationi LEFT JOINStaffBenefit S ON S.Ts_id=i.ID WHERE i.Name = ?
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
```

---

**Table Info**

```
 db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");  //ID=_id
```

**Table Staff_Benefit**

```
 db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT + "( "  + ID3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Claim_Type TEXT, Image BLOB, Description TEXT , Amount TEXT, Ts_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Ts_id) REFERENCES "+TABLE_INFO+"(_id))"); //ID3=_id
```

**LogCat**

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, i.Date, i.TimeIn_Info, i.TimeOut_Info, S.Image FROM Information i LEFT JOIN StaffBenefit S ON S.Ts_id=i._ID WHERE i.Name = ? 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

**Latest query**

```
Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, i.Date, i.TimeIn_Info, i.TimeOut_Info, S.Image FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " i LEFT JOIN "+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT+" S ON S.Ts_id=i._ID WHERE i.Name = ?", new String[]{"XCV"}, null);
```

Comment: `JOINStaffBenefit` no space between JOIN and StaffBenefit

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need whitespace between identifiers and keywords. In particular, replace

```
"i LEFT JOIN"
```

with

```
" i LEFT JOIN "
```

Comment: `(1) ambiguous column name: _id`...Is it because I have `_id` in both tables ?

Comment: Yes, you should add a table name before the _id like my_table._id

Comment: @Orlangure hye, thanks for your response. Can you check my latest query?

Comment: @Seng You still did not change your field name. Try adding either i or S before _id depending of which id you are interested to get: i._id or S._id

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve my second issues,

replace with `Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT i._id, i.Date, i.TimeIn_Info, i.TimeOut_Info, S.Image FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " i LEFT JOIN "+MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT+" S ON S.Ts_id=i._id WHERE i.Name = ?", new String[]{"XCV"}, null);`